# Why did I get a segmentation fault message in a function?

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault

I am in Part 2 on working with the language which basically is about memory and strings. I want to make a function similar to `strcat()` in C, so here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *add_str(char *str, char *str2);

int main() {
    char name[] = "MatthewGamer"; char name2[] = "PlayGames";
    printf("%s\n", add_str(name, name2));
}

char *add_str(char str[], char str2[]) {
    return strcat(str, str2);
}
```

Not that I want to change what's inside my function, but rather a problem after string concatenation. When I ran the program, here is what appeared:

```
~/BPML/C/Phase2/ $ make add_str
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    add_str.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o add_str
~/BPML/C/Phase2/ $ ./add_str
MatthewGamerPlayGames
Segmentation fault
~/BPML/C/Phase2/ $
```

Yep, a segmentation fault is what appeared right after. I don't understand the mechanic behind it even though I already encountered one of these occurings before.

Q: **If the code within the strings are the problem, how do I fix it? If not the strings, then what?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat` requires that the target array has a string that is already null terminated *and* has extra space to hold the entire concatenated string *and* the null terminator, otherwise the *behaviour* will be *undefined*.

The most scaling solution would be to use `strlen`, `malloc` and `memcpy` instead of using `strcat` at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *concatenate(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t s1_len = strlen(s1);
    size_t s2_len = strlen(s2);
    char *ret = malloc(s1_len + s2_len + 1);
    memcpy(ret, s1, s1_len);

    // copy the null terminator too
    memcpy(ret + s1_len, s2, s2_len + 1);
    return ret;
}

int main(void) {
    char *concatenated = concatenate("Hello ", "World!");
    printf("%s\n", concatenate);
    free(concatenated);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your destination string is too short and strcat wtites outside the array bounds. You need to have space there for both strings.

```
int main(void) {
    char name[sizeof("MatthewGamer") + sizeof("PlayGames") - 1] = "MatthewGamer"; char name2[] = "PlayGames";
    printf("%s\n", add_str(name, name2));
}
```